# What does it mean to say that something is a "wash"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I've heard the word "wash" used in unusual context, where it meant something like "a thing yielding no practical advantage". I would be interested to know if that's a correct interpretation, if there are more examples of similar usage and whether this is appropriate for use in formal setting.

Comment: Looks like the usage derived from "wash out" back in the 20's: http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=it+%27+s+a+wash%2C+a+wash+out&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=  https://www.google.com/search?q=%22it%27s%20a%20wash%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1921,cd_max:1938&lr=lang_en

Comment: It's not a particularly unusual meaning. http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/american-english/wash_3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are several idioms having to do with the word "wash": http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/wash

Sadly, while they do not have "it's a wash," it looks like other answers have this informal usage.

However, there is a formal usage in accounting called a [wash sale](http://www.irs.gov/instructions/i1040sd/ch01.html). This is when you sell a security and buy back a substantially similar one within 30 days. This is close to your usage of "a thing yielding no practical advantage." One would sell and buy the stock at about the same price. However, this would allow the one to obtain a capital loss. (This is a practical advantage that the IRS will disallow.)

Comment: "It's a wash" doesn't show up in the idioms list because it's not an idiom: it's a meaning of the word "wash". [See sense 13.](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/wash) of noun usage in the dictionary section.

Comment: Interesting example, thanks. Wash sale is probably an example of a technical term in this case.

Answer (score 0):

We would all benefit from the sentence itself, though you seem close in your interpretation. See: http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=wash.

In its slang meaning the word is not appropriate in any formal setting.

Comment: The original sentence was a bit too technical, dealing with computer architecture, so I omitted it.